# Load model from JSON to child

Tags: json, knockout.js, parent-child, knockout-mapping-plugin

I have model with default data. I want to update model from JSON. 
But child model isn't filled.

For example: I add new group and save the model to JSON, after that I try to load model from JSON, but second group doesn't  have child.

```
 function Condition() {
        var self = this;

        var sqlArea = function(sqlAreaId, displayName) {
            this.displayName = ko.observable(displayName);
            this.sqlAreaId = ko.observable(sqlAreaId);
        };


        self.templateName = "condition-template";


        self.entarea = ko.observableArray([new sqlArea(1, "Client"), 
                                           new sqlArea(2, "Order")]);

        self.selectedArea = ko.observable();
        self.value = ko.observable(0);      

    // ko.mapping.fromJS(data,{},  self);
    }


    function Group() {
        var self = this;

        var logicalOperator = function (logicalOperatorId, logicalOperatorDisplayName) {
            this.logicalOperatorDisplayName = ko.observable(logicalOperatorDisplayName);
            this.logicalOperatorId = ko.observable(logicalOperatorId);
        };


        self.templateName = "group-template";

        self.condition = ko.observableArray();


        self.logoper = ko.observableArray([new logicalOperator(1, "И"), new logicalOperator(2, "ИЛИ")]);

        self.selectedLogoper = ko.observable();
        self.logicalOperatorId = ko.observable(2);


        self.condition.push(new Condition());

        self.addCondition = function () {
            self.condition.push(new Condition());
        };

        self.addGroup = function () {
            self.condition.push(new Group());
        };

        self.removeChild = function (child) {
            self.condition.remove(child);
        };

    }

  function ViewModel() {
        var self = this;          

        self.group = ko.observable(new Group());

        self.save = function() {
        self.lastSavedJson(JSON.stringify( ko.mapping.toJS(self), null, 2));
        var test = document.getElementById('t_test');
        test.innerHTML = (JSON.stringify( ko.mapping.toJS(self), null, 2));     
    };

   self.lastSavedJson = ko.observable("");

    self.loadModel = function() {   

        var test = document.getElementById('t_test');
        var data = JSON.parse(test.innerHTML);

        ko.mapping.fromJS(data,{},  self);

    };  
     }


   ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

jsFiddle: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/Lk3mJ/1/)

**UPDATE: I tried to change model, but I have the same result.**

[Example 2(jsFiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/Lk3mJ/4/)

Comment: I thinkg you want to make `group` an observableArray to begin with. Then push your new groups in it, instead of pushing them in the `condition` observableArray

Comment: I try http://jsfiddle.net/Lk3mJ/2/ , but it doesn't work too.

Comment: I think the mapping plugin updates only the observables it created in the first place. To update you need to do `ko.mapping.fromJS(data, viewmodel)` instead of `ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, viewmodel)` which I believe will remove everything from your viewmodel and put `data` instead (removing methods for example)

Comment: It doesn't work. I think that adding new group to observableArray group is good, but I can't undestand  how to do it correctly!